# cx_Freeze 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' python-3.6

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

Code:

```
import cx_Freeze as f

exe = [f.Executable("C:\\Users\Administrator\\Desktop\\GAME bro\\game.py")]

f.setup(name="cars",options={"build exe":{"packages":["pygame","random","time"],"include_files":["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\GAME bro\\heloo.png"]}},executables=exe)
```

The result when you run this code:

```
running build
running build_exe
creating directory build\exe.win-amd64-3.6
copying C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\game.exe
copying C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python36.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\python36.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.setup(name="cars",options={"build exe":{"packages":["pygame","random","time"],"include_files":["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\GAME bro\\heloo.png"]}},executables=exe)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 618, in Freeze
    self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 227, in _FreezeExecutable
    self._AddVersionResource(exe)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 166, in _AddVersionResource
    trademarks = exe.trademarks)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 751, in __init__
    parts = version.split(".")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

so this is the problem so can somebody help me

so try to run this code

and i am in a windows 10 operating system

and the main part for this problem is this part:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NoneType` object indicates that:

- no data was returned by a function ("void" procedures)
- that a function that should return data was not able to do so ...
- a variable has not been set that is later-on referred to.

In your case the `version.split(".")` fails as "version" is not set. It seems the "version" needs to be added to the `f.setup()` call, i.e. this should work:

```
f.setup(
     name="cars",
     options={
         "build exe":{"packages":["pygame","random","time"],
         "include_files":["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\GAME bro\\heloo.png"]}},
     executables=exe,
     version="1.0.0"
)
```

Please give it a try and let us know if this helped.

Comment: This did work? Nice :-) Would you check the answer as a solution to your question?

Comment: Then take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see everything you can do here on SO. You can also help other people as soon as you become more experienced and give back to the community :-). And thanks for accepting! Good luck with your project!